# HTML node at caret position in contenteditable <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a basic Rich Text Editor (RTE) for a private site we're working on. The site requires the use of an RTE to add blog posts.

Everything is working fine, but I would like to toggle the active state of buttons in the toolbar when they have the specific style applied to them. This works fine for things like bold, italic etc., since we can use `document.queryCommandValue("Bold")`, and so on.

The problem we have is that there is no way to detect things such as `<blockquote />` and `<a />` tags.

We add `<blockquote>` elements to the RTE as follows:

```
// Insert a blockquote:
this._blockquote = function()
{
    // Get the selected text:
    var theText = this._getSelectedText();

    // Are we replacing?
    if(theText != '')
    {
        var quote = $('<blockquote />').html(theText).html();
        this._cmd('inserthtml', '<blockquote>'+quote+'</blockquote>');
    }
    else
    {
        this._cmd('inserthtml', '<blockquote></blockquote>');
    }
}
```

My question is, how can we detect the parent node at the caret position within a `contenteditable` `<div>`? For example, placing my cursor inside the `<blockquote>` node should return 'blockquote' (or something similar).

jQuery is an option.

So, given the following example:

```
<blockquote>Some| <b>text</b></blockquote>
                ^ cursor/caret position
```

I am looking to return `blockquote` (because `Some text` is within a blockquote).

Comment: Is RTE obvious for everybody ("Rich Text Editor" I presume) ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Given some HTML you want to know if a cursor position is inside a blockquote element ?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the question to include a HTML snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is way you can check if to see what sort of an element you are currently in. The function works with chrome. With the recursive function we are able to return the entire array.

```
function returnNodeType()
{
   var node=null;      
   node=window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
   node = ((node.nodeType===1)?node:node.parentNode);      
   var nodeArray = [];
   returnarray = returnParentTag(node, nodeArray);
   return returnarray;
}

function returnParentTag(elem, nodeArray) {
    nodeArray.push(elem.tagName);
    if(elem.id != "editor") {
        var next = returnParentTag(elem.parentNode, nodeArray);
    if(next) return next;
    }
    else
        return nodeArray;
}
```

A jsfiddle link can be found here : http://jsfiddle.net/s6xXH/3

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to get the hierarchy as an array? For example, if placing cursor in the bold text, it should return `b,blockquote` > http://jsfiddle.net/s6xXH/1/

Comment: @BenM should be possible. Just return the parent of the node till you hit an ID of the editor. and keep pushing the node type into an array.

Comment: @BenM Updated the answer with your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This did the trick. Now I need to work on getting it to function in IE!